# Removing part of the legend in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, ggpattern

I have an overlapping of three stat_contour_filled functions using also ggpattern (you can see the "background" [in my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77538122/patterns-in-filled-contours-and-striped-colors-in-r)). Here is my code:

```
v<-ggplot(df, aes(pi1,pi2,z=val))                                                                                                         
v+
stat_contour_filled(geom = 'polygon_pattern', alpha=0.15, bins = 2,
     aes(pattern = after_stat(level),
     fill = after_stat(level)), 
     pattern_spacing = 0.025,
     pattern_size = 0,
     pattern_fill = 'black', 
     pattern_color = 'black',
     pattern_linetype=1,
     pattern_density=0.1, 
     pattern_res=NA,                  
     show.legend=TRUE,
     pattern_angle=45)+ 
stat_contour_filled(data = df2, geom = 'polygon_pattern', alpha=0.15, bins = 2,
     aes(pattern = after_stat(level),
     fill = after_stat(level)), 
     pattern_spacing = 0.025, 
     pattern_size = 0,
     pattern_fill = 'black', pattern_color = 'black', 
     pattern_linetype=1,
     pattern_density=0.1,
     pattern_res=NA,
     show.legend=TRUE,
     pattern_angle=135)+   
stat_contour_filled(data = df3, geom = 'polygon_pattern', alpha=0.3, bins = 2,
     aes(pattern = after_stat(level),
     fill = after_stat(level)))+
scale_pattern_manual(NULL, values = c('stripe', 'stripe', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none'),
     labels = c('A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6')) +
scale_fill_manual(NULL, values = c('white', 'white','white', 'grey30', 'white', 'white'),
     labels = c('A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6')) + #, limits = c("grey30")
theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.title = element_blank(), plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5), axis.title = element_text(size = 13.5))+
xlab(TeX("$\\pi_1$"))+
ylab(TeX("$\\pi_2$"))+
labs(title = "Trial", subtitle = "Trial")+
coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE)
```

df, df1 and df2 are three data frames (I am sorry but I don't know how to let you know the three matrices without pasting the values here). You can see the result below
[image: overlap of three graphs]
As you can notice, the legend is a mess. For what concerns "A1" and "A2", I would like to have lines going only in one direction (45° for A1 and 135° for A2). Then, I also would like to eliminate "A4", "A5" and "A6" from the legend sine they are redundant. How can I do that? Is it possible?

I tried override.aes but it still changes both A1 and A2 (and I didn't find the way to change them separately: for example I can change the pattern angle to 90° in the legend, but this change affects both A1 and A2 in the same way). I tried then to use "limits" trying to eliminate A4, A5 and A6 but it doesn't work: it didn't return an error message, but the result was completely wrong.

EDIT: I put the three matrices reduced to dim 20x20, and give you the pi1 and pi2 to build the data frame.

```
pi1<-seq(0.1,0.29,0.01)
pi2<-seq(0.7,0.89,0.01)
```

below the values for the first df:

```
structure(c(-0.125253923976311, -0.121155269702976, -0.11679250652157, 
-0.112175219142827, -0.107311979370241, -0.102210514925871, -0.0968778480599726, 
-0.0913204103420283, -0.0855441384716247, -0.079554554820631, 
-0.0733568355895018, -0.0669558688417164, -0.0603563042117479, 
-0.053562595722735, -0.0465790388717561, -0.0394098029231559, 
-0.0320589591792331, -0.0245305058621547, -0.0168283901333233, 
-0.00895652769062566, -0.117119415129365, -0.113045672428237, 
-0.10870486364978, -0.104106904706795, -0.099260659546626, -0.0941741139703815, 
-0.0888545182909854, -0.0833085054381917, -0.0775421895012305, 
-0.0715612485337452, -0.0653709945902801, -0.0589764333258955, 
-0.0523823150081714, -0.0455931784214152, -0.0386133888567678, 
-0.0314471711582733, -0.0240986386188761, -0.0165718183808032, 
-0.00887067388377388, -0.000999124815862507, -0.109157460959709, 
-0.105108915215013, -0.10079024122064, -0.0962116964499884, -0.0913824461165366, 
-0.0863107422014924, -0.0810040703390089, -0.0754692713860667, 
-0.0697126428256138, -0.0637400239448799, -0.0575568678475645, 
-0.0511683027013268, -0.044579184125505, -0.037794140243945, 
-0.0308176106335645, -0.0236538801692445, -0.0163071085843858, 
-0.0087813564227387, -0.00108060794259679, 0.00679120855711424, 
-0.101372363896393, -0.0973492428642886, -0.0930528279588135, 
-0.0884937289739591, -0.0836814218737247, -0.0786244332457567, 
-0.0733304915950381, -0.0678066525319898, -0.062059403167135, 
-0.0560947497755235, -0.0499182918820474, -0.0435352852412537, 
-0.0369506956740809, -0.0301692453329502, -0.0231954526639647, 
-0.0160336670983131, -0.00868809931836773, -0.0011628477958614, 
0.00653807781863258, 0.0144107359703134, -0.0937686513556012, 
-0.0897711145847911, -0.0854970163836411, -0.0809573300199627, 
-0.0761618520481488, -0.0711193924081949, -0.0658379303113193, 
-0.0603247432018966, -0.0545865142769045, -0.0486294227512868, 
-0.0424592201157643, -0.0360812949351987, -0.0295007282093091, 
-0.0227223409152437, -0.015750735040156, -0.00859032916840408, 
-0.00124538949586828, 0.00627994300877588, 0.0139816286979295, 
0.0218557080939874, -0.0863511046051821, -0.0823792319917291, 
-0.0781274299692011, -0.0736070468180096, -0.06882820987252, 
-0.0638000214857167, -0.0585307196918221, -0.0530278110996587, 
-0.0472981816722302, -0.041348189709911, -0.0351837443820628, 
-0.0288103724319859, -0.022233275138262, -0.0154573772016319, 
-0.00848736890624968, -0.00132774265355184, 0.00601717523087247, 
0.0135431966743774, 0.0212462474011559, 0.0291223453268672, -0.0791247920221725, 
-0.0751785713624195, -0.0709489544255615, -0.0664476764223569, 
-0.0616852060019481, -0.0566709473021328, -0.051413405574996, 
-0.0459203241709262, -0.0401987987156113, -0.0342553729299377, 
-0.0280961195386621, -0.0217267089718131, -0.0151524680050195, 
-0.00837843005914413, -0.00140937855009704, 0.00575011557817817, 
0.0130956612083147, 0.0206230185247236, 0.0283280739723034, 0.0362068181661002, 
-0.0720951075381432, -0.0681744209197235, -0.0639667738482627, 
-0.0594843007568002, -0.0547378224867451, -0.0497370546420153, 
-0.0444907783638605, -0.0390069815659737, -0.0332929766479196, 
-0.0273554992725534, -0.0212007917569244, -0.0148346738618446, 
-0.00826260319131272, -0.00148972697500516, 0.00547907333186898, 
0.0126391434624317, 0.0199860228066507, 0.0275154151426878, 0.0352231629733984, 
0.0431052249183738, -0.0652678152290666, -0.0613724240708616, 
-0.0571864126344705, -0.0527223272393553, -0.0479913521395993, 
-0.0430035243968618, -0.0377679099898522, -0.0322927494617455, 
-0.0265855793105971, -0.0206533338469495, -0.0145024311740896, 
-0.00813884615938815, -0.00156817267472709, 0.00520432306633861, 
0.0121736565955661, 0.0193350854950991, 0.0266840749306886, 0.0342162675955613, 
0.0419274573859236, 0.0498135662408282, -0.0586491012043584, 
-0.054778629720698, -0.0506137842493782, -0.0461675360347625, 
-0.0414514443110138, -0.0364758779037002, -0.031250196857717, 
-0.0257829026585312, -0.0200817634414878, -0.0141539190541026, 
-0.00800596973476631, -0.00164405136142642, 0.00492610038319424, 
0.0116990950461672, 0.0186698401133574, 0.0258335001484071, 0.0331854613398153, 
0.0407213006120212, 0.0484367585993785, 0.0563277158974527, -0.0522456341923555, 
-0.0483995510133229, -0.0442552481533598, -0.0398261352025006, 
-0.0351241582986704, -0.0301600286607587, -0.0249434099161733, 
-0.019483073057336, -0.0137870256130174, -0.00786262004165938, 
-0.00171664521968984, 0.00464459593479816, 0.0112152202862406, 
0.0179897078124003, 0.0249628528687348, 0.0321297221022382, 0.0394856179598101, 
0.047026046919527, 0.0547466917207986, 0.0626433869888736, -0.0460646365176799, 
-0.0422422341443053, -0.038117676479399, -0.0337048252776739, 
-0.0290160258769486, -0.0240623428565618, -0.0188537532422565, 
-0.0133993063589438, -0.00770725710840564, -0.00178517782195931, 
0.0043599473282116, 0.0107216422304496, 0.0172938705592343, 0.0240709773246142, 
0.0310476386233209, 0.0382188182665171, 0.0455797301950511, 0.0531258057820735, 
0.0608526652752758, 0.0687560927545358, -0.040113967533861, -0.0363143392421465, 
-0.0322085323948595, -0.0278108751553089, -0.0231341247549187, 
-0.0181897104601333, -0.0129879328281693, -0.00753812861653586, 
-0.00184880831280176, 0.00407222842286975, 0.0102177953074264, 
0.016581236758893, 0.0231563574329192, 0.0299373619109036, 0.036918802867009, 
0.0440955363467619, 0.0514626830327637, 0.0590155945678539, 0.0667498241633993, 
0.0746611008481022, -0.0344022220309195, -0.0306242357594972, 
-0.0265359625095824, -0.0221522115626734, -0.0174861651717056, 
-0.0125496290074562, -0.00735323763421458, -0.00190662463620517, 
0.00378143545314225, 0.00970290798558032, 0.015850397589854, 
0.0222170628127331, 0.0287965433731411, 0.0355828979063091, 0.0425705504732966, 
0.0497542444249786, 0.0571290024595041, 0.0646900919130227, 0.0724329944858928, 
0.0803533797386226, -0.028938846707694, -0.0251811153674918, 
-0.0211089062279814, -0.0167375249230974, -0.0120805923405181, 
-0.00715030270567124, -0.00195763544211847, 0.00348746932469723, 
0.00917596428876349, 0.0150995719382088, 0.0212506806666189, 
0.0276222566220209, 0.0342077685817957, 0.0410011236669811, 0.0479966121178883, 
0.0551888596751998, 0.0625727863678181, 0.0701435707156787, 0.0778966185233829, 
0.0858275355769907, -0.0237342785178908, -0.0199951260450024, 
-0.0159372256205763, -0.0115763950720718, -0.00692670808977158, 
-0.00200076009386008, 0.0031901133589094, 0.00863565553221984, 
0.014326537328514, 0.0202542302629563, 0.0264108991670516, 0.0327893111320052, 
0.0393827579034302, 0.0461849894760119, 0.0531901570551885, 0.0603927638837107, 
0.0677876226953951, 0.0753698187716277, 0.0831346777492044, 0.0910777374691544, 
-0.0188001096182287, -0.015077531949236, -0.0110318602600635, 
-0.006679441131069, -0.00203481586953647, 0.00288900570554784, 
0.00808032015007876, 0.0135285436471448, 0.019224055963363, 0.0251580692750403, 
0.0313225173309682, 0.0377099613709817, 0.0443135099342657, 0.0511267502397794, 
0.0581436892495296, 0.0653587028648487, 0.0727664919777908, 0.080362044319456, 
0.0881406012256236, 0.0960976285858458, -0.0141492848428813, 
-0.0104409048205839, -0.0064050126033009, -0.0020585009500389, 
0.00258360563402005, 0.00750786906742551, 0.0127022057093441, 
0.0181556937351774, 0.0238584120639713, 0.0298013048816523, 0.0359760671221904, 
0.0423750472350535, 0.048991164294362, 0.0558178370644661, 0.0628489230748315, 
0.0700786661052529, 0.0775016507620214, 0.0851127630519991, 0.0929071560458163, 
0.100880219872025, -0.00979633921847556, -0.00609935422998314, 
-0.00207037101909469, 0.00227315299045328, 0.00691569359323674, 
0.0118433697995546, 0.0170437048117794, 0.0225054273404201, 0.0282183053242966, 
0.0341730059848675, 0.0403609774749318, 0.0467743483595375, 0.0534058419049188, 
0.0602487027210534, 0.0672966337512911, 0.0745437419594562, 0.0819844913522391, 
0.0896136622078261, 0.0974263155718293, 0.105417762237173, -0.00575768520614423, 
-0.00206880610811477, 0.00195662035310895, 0.00630055229091164, 
0.0109469481766642, 0.0158814685279062, 0.0210912296577792, 0.0265645987319593, 
0.0322910220873608, 0.0382608806370392, 0.0444653675225237, 0.0508963841609735, 
0.0575464515822344, 0.064408634530612, 0.0714764762637092, 0.0787439423465477, 
0.0862053720345977, 0.0938554360794709, 0.101689099987148, 0.109701591919325
), dim = c(20L, 20L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("X21", "X22", "X23", 
"X24", "X25", "X26", "X27", "X28", "X29", "X30", "X31", "X32", 
"X33", "X34", "X35", "X36", "X37", "X38", "X39", "X40")))
```

below the values for df2:

```
structure(c(0.104059420093876, 0.101690424941149, 0.0988789500224057, 
0.0956612835194564, 0.0920691255691727, 0.0881301952516481, 0.0838687317797954, 
0.0793059120650528, 0.0744602013549112, 0.0693476496584907, 0.0639821437504054, 
0.0583756223685768, 0.052538260590023, 0.0464786281337833, 0.0402038253979054, 
0.0337196003128182, 0.0270304485317741, 0.020139699040286, 0.0130495869210026, 
0.00576131473634501, 0.0956790227953769, 0.0933783581644555, 
0.0906294963098807, 0.0874693688570872, 0.083930178746482, 0.0800400328847408, 
0.0758234629857831, 0.0713018582595197, 0.0664938277299099, 0.0614155057021371, 
0.056080810768695, 0.0505016664197756, 0.0446881895802659, 0.038648852076996, 
0.032390619034102, 0.0259190674212247, 0.019238487380308, 0.0123519684891078, 
0.00526147275149297, -0.00203210418728744, 0.0874637503503461, 
0.0852325669955699, 0.0825467378437661, 0.0794439298712676, 0.0759569256772685, 
0.0721142848330412, 0.0679408867222105, 0.0634583801845866, 0.0586855589542968, 
0.0536386773060622, 0.0483317169661869, 0.0427766138538879, 0.0369834513518432, 
0.0309606253933007, 0.0247149855769539, 0.0182519556939201, 0.0115756364108956, 
0.00468889235391752, -0.00240657455586412, -0.00971016397464431, 
0.0794002351282541, 0.0772398915825746, 0.0746177140601908, 0.0715722017672361, 
0.0681367975074447, 0.064340581074287, 0.0602088366682658, 0.055763521499547, 
0.0510236559149689, 0.0460056504590559, 0.0407235816677828, 0.0351894257174711, 
0.0294132570469787, 0.0234034175567426, 0.0171666608340808, 0.0107082749677722, 
0.00403218682892693, -0.00285894983991608, -0.00996368060622466, 
-0.0172816892117271, 0.0714763219414494, 0.0693883490248672, 
0.0668306037394789, 0.0638425199757751, 0.0604582854217363, 0.0567075706981643, 
0.0526161241930747, 0.0482062618220917, 0.0434972735595285, 0.0385057632603431, 
0.0332459343987641, 0.0277298314661503, 0.0219675446133492, 0.0159673834936189, 
0.00973602502139407, 0.0032786388097687, -0.00340100668714634, 
-0.0103004548751434, -0.0174184865636179, -0.0247550587092801, 
0.0636811139805045, 0.0616671725556517, 0.0591747580135973, 0.0562443475653639, 
0.0529109630261656, 0.0492049398007248, 0.0451525522738464, 0.0407765271491111, 
0.0360964682644919, 0.0311292106455645, 0.0258891173449689, 0.0203883295022877, 
0.0146369777304011, 0.00864336117750469, 0.00241409927683893, 
-0.00404573982958574, -0.0107325309999536, -0.0176440013587937, 
-0.0247791550300942, -0.032138211631665, 0.0560050521748338, 
0.0540668817478627, 0.0516407621681877, 0.0487683293792162, 0.0454855335306667, 
0.0418234523853919, 0.037808950745498, 0.0334652200406956, 0.028812223494904, 
0.0238670660197508, 0.0186443034149916, 0.0131562020822723, 0.00741295793953592, 
0.00142288132397792, -0.00480744677308126, -0.0112730429034265, 
-0.0179704104107843, -0.0248974470168358, -0.0320533685528469, 
-0.0394386470594756, 0.0484400344435459, 0.0465793896094439, 
0.0442205315725082, 0.0414063777563806, 0.0381739061681027, 0.0345550183288138, 
0.0305772366013528, 0.0262642729828161, 0.0216364968971231, 0.0167113226921495, 
0.0115035325760619, 0.00602554706287842, 0.000287652264035437, 
-0.00570180869612116, -0.0119362744274983, -0.0184108296690372, 
-0.0251220917411327, -0.0320681161853773, -0.039248319285849, 
-0.0466634156130323, 0.0409795832333808, 0.0391981541907626, 
0.0369074486730557, 0.0341517961615063, 0.0309693076290954, 0.0273927937031745, 
0.0234505041987412, 0.0191667293884467, 0.0145622929288118, 0.00965495889495935, 
0.00445976995348557, -0.00101067028917564, -0.00674596069941656, 
-0.0127377039643981, -0.0189793397483021, -0.0254660048299765, 
-0.0321944163976641, -0.0391627754557848, -0.0463706879094945, 
-0.0538191013758431, 0.0336190721868492, 0.0319183845491209, 
0.0296965500120458, 0.0269994488993936, 0.0238664359888798, 0.0203313203048396, 
0.0164231516568093, 0.0121668580173452, 0.00758376634776275, 
0.00269203129162025, -0.00249300977908682, -0.00795854124225912, 
-0.0136940223508141, -0.0196909805657309, -0.0259428385076244, 
-0.0324447693513226, -0.0391935765771412, -0.0461875948382199, 
-0.0534266093653668, -0.0609117918540426, 0.0263560259058579, 
0.0247373137493051, 0.0225847748139195, 0.0199459874504186, 0.0168616667653039, 
0.0133667132259618, 0.009491051562089, 0.00526030827953604, 0.00069636343560092, 
-0.00418219668436775, -0.0093597058650926, -0.0148231078913256, 
-0.0205616983181892, -0.0265669089561386, -0.0328321279637638, 
-0.0393525499832288, -0.0461250519392662, -0.0531480910423693, 
-0.060421622255953, -0.0679470330548286, 0.0191905107936668, 
0.0176545552243543, 0.0155712900038341, 0.0129901469985148, 0.00995332352985363, 
0.00649690786255787, 0.0026517764510945, -0.00155568394258733, 
-0.00610299016488776, -0.0109710834690494, -0.0161439352224895, 
-0.0216082208059841, -0.0273530488864527, -0.033369736167258, 
-0.0396516199300947, -0.0461939023677236, -0.0529935220015425, 
-0.0600490484804119, -0.0673605978397468, -0.0749297659166289, 
0.012125640174557, 0.0106725635536734, 0.00865791083472607, 0.00613313066698951, 
0.00314202911012116, -0.000278018923200733, -0.00409510739968434, 
-0.00828202749579818, -0.0128156435140671, -0.0176763843871032, 
-0.0228478267031222, -0.0283163509856646, -0.0340708572538463, 
-0.0401025291024747, -0.0464046379676747, -0.0529723810906687, 
-0.0598027481090226, -0.0668944122995728, -0.074247643350486, 
-0.0818642392111096, 0.00516822373419845, 0.00379722692705052, 
0.0018496419622992, -0.000620895841498778, -0.00356884182417896, 
-0.0069554343975726, -0.0107476603197635, -0.0149174280100452, 
-0.019440901428289, -0.0242979592837619, -0.0294717531352667, 
-0.0349483443633396, -0.0407164047392324, -0.0467669688591616, 
-0.0530932293835741, -0.0596903680508513, -0.0665554169886149, 
-0.0736871460441687, -0.0810859727875089, -0.0887538925718459, 
-0.00167039958933922, -0.00296137318309235, -0.00484462866209025, 
-0.00726416960971302, -0.0101725816701766, -0.0135296173958312, 
-0.0173010808066954, -0.0214579396873888, -0.0259756130423214, 
-0.0308333947855031, -0.0360139845328948, -0.0415031034954149, 
-0.0472891787300193, -0.0533630829271471, -0.0597179198622511, 
-0.0663488478753333, -0.0732529354503357, -0.0804290442804212, 
-0.0878777362245963, -0.0956012013593626, -0.00837329389711427, 
-0.00958798849174783, -0.0114112405485412, -0.0137845169733518, 
-0.0166584046231051, -0.0199910748309895, -0.0237470781377234, 
-0.0278963890272818, -0.0324136422384856, -0.0372775175155003, 
-0.0424702406004484, -0.0479771762206597, -0.0537864946737367, 
-0.0598888979654249, -0.0662773947210703, -0.0729471155612835, 
-0.0798951625138372, -0.0871204874775046, -0.0946237958702334, 
-0.102407472465937, -0.0149165556863655, -0.0160609546123937, 
-0.0178306196001182, -0.0201643094056288, -0.0230104898137599, 
-0.0263256636904582, -0.0300730659186981, -0.0342216335261518, 
-0.0387451858529193, -0.0436217668007134, -0.0488331134766662, 
-0.054364224440634, -0.0602030072958038, -0.0663399902074405, 
-0.0727680855604261, -0.0794823967003296, -0.0864800607790789, 
-0.0937601223145091, -0.101323433297545, -0.109172576633673, 
-0.0212675487959533, -0.0223505828067474, -0.0240758092517447, 
-0.0263791192567133, -0.0292067490165405, -0.0325134598452003, 
-0.0362611225719543, -0.0404176056106352, -0.0449558938062474, 
-0.0498533845762253, -0.0550913216850642, -0.0606543369831872, 
-0.0665300777556512, -0.0727089027360825, -0.0791836338764611, 
-0.0859493539957875, -0.0930032427254083, -0.100344444917658, 
-0.107973967027857, -0.11589459802124, -0.0273826201966347, -0.0284170791979203, 
-0.0301105700418412, -0.0323959802854633, -0.035217231686733, 
-0.0385272935024849, -0.0422866450224231, -0.0464620739269206, 
-0.0510257286416676, -0.0559543648785928, -0.0612287421826687, 
-0.0668331375686694, -0.0727549515499355, -0.0789843879167856, 
-0.0855141931217798, -0.0923394444969213, -0.0994573790660795, 
-0.106867256642327, -0.114570252373453, -0.122569375036642, -0.0332041234121185, 
-0.0342078335811067, -0.0358869032959315, -0.0381711207700544, 
-0.0410020460347818, -0.0443308399220627, -0.0481165932340577, 
-0.0523250278892438, -0.056927477921835, -0.0619000832909366, 
-0.0672231472007773, -0.0728806203737145, -0.0788596849742894, 
-0.0851504176737684, -0.0917455163678688, -0.0986400788028138, 
-0.105831424172148, -0.11331895086739, -0.121104025180191, -0.129189896994519
), dim = c(20L, 20L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("X21", "X22", "X23", 
"X24", "X25", "X26", "X27", "X28", "X29", "X30", "X31", "X32", 
"X33", "X34", "X35", "X36", "X37", "X38", "X39", "X40")))
```

below the values for df3:

```
structure(c(0.0352779411045854, 0.027229449988019, 0.0188569345879069, 
0.0101413847358512, 0.00106233584918369, -0.00840226807237843, 
-0.0182762268256291, -0.0285852537748059, -0.0393571653366023, 
-0.0506220928599478, -0.0624127200035062, -0.0747645492125898, 
-0.0877162014882341, -0.10130975434402, -0.11559112368509, -0.130610496348729, 
-0.146422821254593, -0.163088368572358, -0.180673368085114, -0.199250740083915, 
0.0177975018044949, 0.00949277239193047, 0.000861975782358249, 
-0.00811359781821253, -0.0174540607666872, -0.0271810575890807, 
-0.0373179088649674, -0.0478897712287817, -0.0589238156000599, 
-0.0704494260748383, -0.0824984222862304, -0.0951053084847412, 
-0.108307553111669, -0.122145903258561, -0.136664739142702, -0.151912474608315, 
-0.167942010717348, -0.184811250761738, -0.202583686560815, -0.22132906776565, 
0.00122955063852626, -0.00731183423050386, -0.0161806493396538, 
-0.025395283787685, -0.0349754781197162, -0.0449424468852249, 
-0.0553190144543524, -0.0661297657693175, -0.0774012139526485, 
-0.0891619869798822, -0.101443035959074, -0.114277867952465, 
-0.127702806738498, -0.14175728545923, -0.156484175746447, -0.171930158691003, 
-0.188146143940601, -0.205187744314646, -0.223115814652425, -0.241997065214695, 
-0.0144492100561046, -0.0232091518292356, -0.0322972868774251, 
-0.0417316680254578, -0.0515316494197896, -0.061718002389261, 
-0.0723130436176206, -0.0833407771576121, -0.0948270520358756, 
-0.106799737453459, -0.119288917885101, -0.132327110729757, -0.145949509575058, 
-0.160194256621566, -0.175102748383658, -0.190719979460856, -0.207094929978853, 
-0.224281003261264, -0.242336521445938, -0.26132528814687, -0.0292590511114141, 
-0.0382208052648607, -0.0475109863787226, -0.0571472994253051, 
-0.0671487017587417, -0.0775355126259449, -0.0883295341121154, 
-0.0995541849170303, -0.111234648555181, -0.123398037801423, 
-0.136073577469987, -0.149292807925521, -0.163089812088794, -0.177501469127109, 
-0.192567738523059, -0.208331978810374, -0.224841305971341, -0.242146997330038, 
-0.260304947778558, -0.279376186375651, -0.0432172921216614, 
-0.0523653500832331, -0.0618416018983179, -0.0716633964777181, 
-0.0818492875002317, -0.092419136914065, -0.103394229060489, 
-0.114797396694762, -0.126653160355967, -0.138987882742132, -0.151829939984658, 
-0.165209911992999, -0.179160794363758, -0.193718234727022, -0.208920796847439, 
-0.224810256321532, -0.241431932332059, -0.258835060654801, -0.277073213987269, 
-0.296204776713019, -0.0563383509783408, -0.0656583327908364, 
-0.0753058639684809, -0.0852979319839434, -0.0956526828894138, 
-0.106389519138611, -0.117529207279388, -0.12909399668191, -0.141107750626087, 
-0.153596091255341, -0.166586560116317, -0.180108796250994, -0.194194734095165, 
-0.208878823773057, -0.224198276771132, -0.240193340436128, -0.256907605286828, 
-0.274388349772632, -0.292686927875417, -0.311859205859788, -0.0686337672698757, 
-0.0781123237117797, -0.0879174227409466, -0.0980656873896987, 
-0.108574854572431, -0.119463867546351, -0.130752977547615, -0.142463855667968, 
-0.154619716179686, -0.167245452681149, -0.180367788625522, -0.194015444015444, 
-0.208219320302567, -0.223012705829054, -0.238431504496394, -0.254514490754922, 
-0.271303594486777, -0.28884421991993, -0.307185603378842, -0.326381215469613, 
-0.0801121990019117, -0.0897369220151024, -0.099686862039062, 
-0.109978276646869, -0.120628494125887, -0.131656000882112, -0.143080537377114, 
-0.154923203572026, -0.167206574981451, -0.179954830587871, -0.193193894037527, 
-0.206951589735684, -0.221257815687442, -0.236144735195412, -0.251646989834497, 
-0.267801936484853, -0.284649911626859, -0.302234526598629, -0.320602998102063, 
-0.339806518935687, -0.0907793915949759, -0.100538731979407, 
-0.110621683511846, -0.121044138936031, -0.13182302008886, -0.14297636053922, 
-0.154523396165125, -0.166484664561355, -0.178882114285361, -0.19173922508206, 
-0.205081140380891, -0.218934813534765, -0.233329169474258, -0.248295283686519, 
-0.263866580702731, -0.280079054597574, -0.296971514377584, -0.314585857572806, 
-0.332967375860239, -0.352165097153653, -0.10063811756876, -0.110521308993869, 
-0.12072625949095, -0.13126849896645, -0.142164546345315, -0.153431987720761, 
-0.165089561893012, -0.177157254114382, -0.189656398962356, -0.202609793381821, 
-0.216041821074777, -0.229978589573724, -0.244448081517039, -0.259480321855144, 
-0.275107562960332, -0.291364489896627, -0.308288448436485, -0.325919698797129, 
-0.344301698521641, -0.363481418461494, -0.109688084707536, -0.119685073160991, 
-0.130001752496832, -0.140653292892275, -0.151655815000957, -0.163026463875703, 
-0.174783489772346, -0.186946336584032, -0.199535738749582, -0.212573827587056, 
-0.226084248127044, -0.240092287661739, -0.254625017388847, -0.269711448717329, 
-0.285382706019326, -0.301672217864541, -0.318615929066128, -0.336252536208321, 
-0.354623749724664, -0.373774586062851, -0.117925809796822, -0.128027187643919, 
-0.138445998598084, -0.149197057119387, -0.160296091110249, -0.17175981185891, 
-0.183605990394304, -0.195853540939996, -0.208522612239854, -0.22163468762523, 
-0.235212694804311, -0.249281126481516, -0.263866173060788, -0.278995868854694, 
-0.294700253415073, -0.311011549825179, -0.327964362053105, -0.345595893768296, 
-0.363946191374942, -0.383058414427343, -0.125344454199841, -0.135541398061704, 
-0.146053350968889, -0.156894776397275, -0.168081015706018, -0.17962835433544, 
-0.191554093981917, -0.203876631381232, -0.216615544408751, -0.229791686292405, 
-0.243427288834388, -0.257546075651814, -0.272173386577579, -0.287336314513075, 
-0.303063856197594, -0.319387078558983, -0.336339302541127, -0.353956306571689, 
-0.372276552144768, -0.391341434356003, -0.131933616569568, -0.142217828244712, 
-0.152814478978712, -0.163737686557984, -0.175002412528672, -0.186624524869023, 
-0.198620866236851, -0.211009328372392, -0.223808933306493, -0.237039922103213, 
-0.250723851956082, -0.26488370256015, -0.279543992799637, -0.294730908925825, 
-0.310472445554717, -0.326798560992245, -0.343741348600482, -0.361335226156207, 
-0.379617145428918, -0.398626824526037, -0.137679076825314, -0.148042726475941, 
-0.158716116940803, -0.169713026034335, -0.181048042598154, -0.192736625854855, 
-0.204795169964882, -0.217241074320198, -0.230092820171561, -0.243370054257834, 
-0.257093680187114, -0.271285958412247, -0.285970615749077, -0.301172965506836, 
-0.316920039438776, -0.333240732880467, -0.350165964626589, -0.367728853308633, 
-0.385964912280702, -0.404912265304387, -0.142562484107478, -0.152998154906745, 
-0.163740755185809, -0.174803728804701, -0.186201299260753, -0.197948525918101, 
-0.210061365095773, -0.222556736505649, -0.235452595588742, -0.248768012363147, 
-0.26252325747054, -0.276739896191796, -0.291440891297573, -0.3066507157085, 
-0.322395476063982, -0.33870304844125, -0.355603227630034, -0.373127891556802, 
-0.391311182670046, -0.410189708349772, -0.146560979690157, -0.157061613076376, 
-0.167866264341071, -0.178988049598038, -0.190440834499856, -0.202239287525271, 
-0.21439893780603, -0.226936237945684, -0.239868632334832, -0.253214631526071, 
-0.266993893298475, -0.281227311117037, -0.295937110778347, -0.311146956131757, 
-0.326882064876905, -0.34316933556634, -0.360037487088401, -0.377517212073786, 
-0.395641345862931, -0.414445052894875, -0.149646743688243, -0.160205584291508, 
-0.171065441491531, -0.182239109955207, -0.193740105027446, -0.205582713247065, 
-0.217782047106268, -0.230354104470867, -0.243315833125641, -0.256685200962527, 
-0.270481272389699, -0.284724291607895, -0.2994357734779, -0.314638602791313, 
-0.330357142857143, -0.346617354431506, -0.363446926148841, -0.380875417763446, 
-0.398934417682872, -0.41765771647359, -0.151786451724806, -0.162396990914223, 
-0.173305464151962, -0.184524350956276, -0.196066823844941, -0.207946796239214, 
-0.220178974336938, -0.23277891333964, -0.245763078461423, -0.259148911195928, 
-0.272954901372308, -0.287200665593045, -0.301907032716502, -0.317096137126678, 
-0.332791520623059, -0.349018243866555, -0.365803008435132, -0.383174290677355, 
-0.401162488706309, -0.419800084053643), dim = c(20L, 20L))
```

In order not to go over the carachters limit, I just put the values. The data frames should be built with the values of pi1 and pi2 I wrote above.
Below, instead, the corresponding part of the graph I have taken with the data I am passing to you:
[image: The part of the graph for the values of alfa and beta I reported]

Comment: _"I am sorry but I don't know how to let you know the three matrices without pasting the values here"_ - the answer is to type `dput(df)` into your console, then copy/paste the output into a code block in your question. Do the same for `dput(df2)` and `dput(df3)`. It looks like this was suggested in the comments to your last question.

Comment: The use of `dput(x)`, `read.table(text='..')`, `data.frame(...)`, and others are discussed at length in https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, an oft-linked page in comments on SO (in the [tag:r] tag, at least). It's not onerous, easy to read, has many examples of how to use the various options, and each of the options come with advantages/disadvantages (to both the asker and us, the consumers). Realize that often we don't need the full data to get the point across: if you can reduce it to (say) 20-30 rows of sample data and simplified code, it's far simpler for us to adapt and fix. Thanks!

Comment: Many thanks, tonight when home I will do it with all the three data frames.